Allowed to select ranges which have disabled days Flatpickr
I am trying to use flatpickr's range calendar in my project. In their docks it is mentioned, that if you try to select a range which has disabled days, it will not be allowed. However, when i try this function on mobile devices, it doesnt work. It just allows you to select a range with disabled days. What could be the problem? Here is my code:
$('#flatPickerCalendar').flatpickr({
            mode: 'range', // Enables range selection
            dateFormat: 'Y/m/d', // Date format
            minDate: "today",
            disable: [
                {
                    from: "2024-07-15",
                    to: "2024-07-22"
                },
                "2024-07-29",
            ],
        })

picture of the calendar and which days are disabled
here is the input after I have selected the range
Tried to take the exact same example that wokrs for them, and that still didn't work
